# How to make a stair railing

Tags: stairs, design

So I'm trying to design a stair railing and I have to have the spaces between the bars to be 4". I just can't think of the way to do the math that would tell me how wide the bars would have to be.

My bars are more like panels.

Railing length: 15' 7 3/16" Design wants: I want one of the ends of the railing to end with a bar/panel. I would like the panels to have a min width of 2".

discussion architecture

Comment: The typical requirement is "less than 4" or "does not allow passage of a 4" ball" (infant head simulation) rather than precisely 4"

Comment: Ok, I was just wanted that because I want the most for light to bable to pass through

Comment: Is the specified length the actual rail length (diagonal) or the horizontal distance the railing covers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce it to inches. 15 feet is 180 inches, plus 7 & 3/16 inches

Total distance 187.1875 inches. Divide by 6 (4" space and 2" slat) 31.1979166666667

Per *my understanding of stair code* (LESS than 4", not 4") use 32 2" slats. Or 3" or 4" slats, for that matter.

Alternatively, divide by 32 (proposed number of slats) and get a unit (slat and space) of 5.849609375 ; or divide by 31 and get a unit of 6.0383064516129

Comment: What did you mean when you said "Reduce it to inches. 15 feet is 180 inches, plus 7 & 3/16 inches" ?

Comment: The math is more straightforward if you have it all in inches, rather than feet and inches. 12 inches to a foot, so 180 inches in 15 feet; then you had an additional 7-3/16.

Comment: So then I just divide the length of the railing by what?

Comment: Slow down and read, I told you this 3 different ways in the answer as written.

Comment: The Big Bang Theory would be proud. Btw, yes, by code it's, "so that a 4" sphere cannot pass."

Comment: Sorry for not paying attention

Comment: thanks for the help, Do happen to know how to take a comment chat to a "chat"